# loading images while swiping in both directions?

Tags: javascript

I implemented this example of hammertime in my website to swipe between images:
https://rawgit.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/master/tests/manual/nested.html

Now I want to create a voting like in a "HOT OR NOT"-voting, so at the the beginning there are only 2 images. But depending on if I swipe right to vote for HOT or swipe left to vote for NOT.

So it would look like this, but the user can't see the next (2nd) image before swiping:
[2] [1] [2]

So if I swipe right image [2] is appearing and [3] will be the next image and so on, no matter if I swipe right or left, because swiping just says if I think someone is hot or not. So this whole system is unlimited.

What should I change in the code to be able to swipe in both directions instead of only to the right like in the example and see the next image in both directions?

Do I have to change something in these lines?

```
        onPan : function (ev) {

            var indexNow = this.currentIndex;
            var delta = dirProp(this.direction, ev.deltaX, ev.deltaY);
            var percent = (100 / this.containerSize) * delta;
            var animate = false;
            if (ev.type == 'panend' || ev.type == 'pancancel') {
                if (Math.abs(percent) > 20 && ev.type == 'panend') {
                    this.currentIndex += (percent < 0) ? 1 : -1;
                }
                percent = 0;
                animate = true;
            }
            this.show(this.currentIndex, percent, animate);
```

Comment: it seems you are attempting to have 2 different functionalities on ONE element using IDENTICAL swipe methods. This cannot be done. It's either scrolling, or "voting"

Comment: But I want to implement the same behaviour all major hot-or-not apps like Lovoo use. How do they do it then? @Unamata Sanatarai